# How can I refresh the index.htm of an angularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I made an application with angularJs and I have a lot of views in there. I work a lot with routing as well. My problem is, I have an index page, that contains a searchbar. And this searchbar has to switch its controller, depending on the current path. But since the searchbar belongs to the index page it doesn't refresh its path (correct me, if I'm wrong here).

Is there a possibility to force the entire page to reload or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, the search bar should not place at index.html.

A better solution is, you can make a shared HTML page which can switch its controller depending on the current path.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to split it up a little bit further, and have the following available:

- searchBar directive/component containing the input, history, etc.
- SearchService service which the searchBar can call when the search text changes.  This will also allow other components to connect to.

For example if you have multiple controllers:

```
searchService.onSearch(function(searchFor){....});
```

Each controller can then provide a search listener to the SearchService.  You don't need to "change controllers" in your searchBar, nor make any real changes to SearchService unless enhancing.  But each active Controller can now perform it's own searching.

In something like this that I use, I have (MemberController):

```
searchService.onLookup(function(lookup){ ... perform lookup to populate drop down ...});
searchService.onSelected(function(selected) { ... now get all the information re: selected member ...});
```

If you have multiple views due to nesting, you can have addOnSearch() instead, to provide a list of callbacks, but this would require that you remove them correctly $onDestroy.